# Copy divs height and apply it to an other div with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

```
<div class="thisOne">
</div>

<div class="thisHeight">
</div>
```

I want to copy thisHeight divs height and apply it to thisOne div, so as the result this two divs will always have the same height.

Comment: when you want to apply this height? on which event?

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following in javascript:

```
 const height = document.getElementsByClassName('thisHeight')[0].offsetHeight;
 document.getElementsByClassName('thisOne')[0].style.height = `${height}px`;
```

I don't know what your endgoal is, but I would suggest taking a look at flexbox to have a CSS only solution.

information can be found here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

1. find that element
2. get its offsetheight
3. find the other element
4. set its height

```
const elem = document.querySelector(`.thisHeight`);
const elemHeight = elem.offsetHeight;
const secondElem = document.querySelector(`.thisOne `);
secondElem.style.height = elemHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply more than one CSS to a single div as follows (by separating with a single space in between):

```
<div class="thisOne thisHeight">
</div>
```

This will copy all the styling in thisHeight so if you want to just use the height, you should separate it out into a separate style.

```
<style>
thisOne {... }

thisOneHeight {... }

myHeight {
     height : 100px;
          }
</style>

<body>

<div class="thisOne myHeight"></div>

<div class="thisHeight myHeight"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably looking for `.getBoundingClientRect()` function to get computed height and width of an element

```js
var thisHeight = document.querySelector(".thisHeight"),
    thisOne = document.querySelector(".thisOne")
    
function copyHeight(from,to){
    to.style.height = from.getBoundingClientRect().height + "px"
}

copyHeight(thisHeight,thisOne)
```

```css
.border {border:1px solid gray;}
```

```html
<div class="thisOne border">
    copied height
</div>

<div class="thisHeight border">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla maxime pariatur quia libero vitae blanditiis velit temporibus? Esse modi perspiciatis consectetur eius nihil magnam, quaerat, dignissimos nisi unde quas quod!
</div>
```